# Steps involved in editing existing PDF documents

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a good indepth description of what happen when you open and modify an existing PDF document.

This could be adding extra content to an existing page. Another example could be removing an existing page and add a new one.

It's not clear to me which steps should happen e.g. when adding existing content or removing it from a page. What should happen to indirect references? What should happen to the xref table, etc...

Is there a good resource that explains step-by-step which steps should happen?

for example (and I'm sure it is not correct, just an example):

1. create new image xobject
2. add it to the xref table
3. remove existing object from page
4. remove it from xref table
5. scan every object to find if it refers to the xref entry
6. ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO this question is way too broad. A *good indepth description* might be possible for a very specific example, e.g. "given this pdf <link>, I want to replace the image (exact specification which image is meant) by this one <link>". For use case descriptions as generic as in your question you cannot hope for anything better than a vague description.

Comment: Concerning your example work flow: why do you want to remove an object from the cross references merely because you removed it from a single position on a single page? Often enough image resources are re-used multiple times in a single pdf.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out how it works if an existing pdf is being modified. Trying to figure out the steps that need to be taken care of from a helicopter point of view.

Comment: That very much depends. Some pdf processors parse the pdf into internal structures, manipulate these structures, and eventually save them as new pdf; the result internally may look very different from the original, different object numbers, some indirect objects turned into direct ones and vice versa, etc. Some processors try to change as little as possible. Some are somewhere in-between.

Comment: is there a recommended way? Or where can I find general information on "editing pdf documents" (related to the internal structure and not software how to edit them :-) )

Comment: There is only a specification showing how an existing pdf shall be structured internally (ISO 32000 parts 1 and 2). Only for a single special situation there are some requirements on how changes have to be applied, for signed pdfs.